# Certificate wildcard SAN gets ignored?

Tags: openssl, x509

So I've created a cert with openssl that contains, among others, *.dev and d.dev in it's SAN.
For some reason accessing https://d.dev works but accessing https://c.dev fails with `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

The commands

```
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key.pem 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -subj '/C=DE/ST=00/O=mkg20001, Inc.' -nodes -key rootCA.key.pem -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt.pem
openssl genrsa -out "dev.key.pem" 4096
openssl req -new -sha256 \
    -key "dev.key.pem" \
    -subj "/C=DE/ST=00/O=mkg20001, Inc./CN=dev" \
    -extensions SAN \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
        <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName='DNS.1:dev,DNS.2:*.dev,DNS.3:*.*.dev,DNS.4:d.dev'")) \
    -out "dev.csr.pem"
openssl x509 -req -extensions SAN -extfile <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
        <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName='DNS.1:dev,DNS.2:*.dev,DNS.3:*.*.dev,DNS.4:d.dev'")) -in "dev.csr.pem" -CA rootCA.crt.pem -CAkey rootCA.key.pem -CAcreateserial -out "dev.crt.pem" -days 500 -sha256
```

The certificate

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard certificates are valid for subdomains, not for top level domains.

For example *.mydomain.com is a valid wildcard certificate, and all https  subdomains (a.mydomain.com, b.mydomain.com) will be valid, but *.com references to the TLD and since it's not a valid subdomain, the wildcard certificate it's not accepted.

References:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain